# spaCy strange behaviour in identifying syntactic dependents

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, dependencies, spacy

I am trying to use `sapCy` to identify syntactic dependents. I tried the same example explained [here](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#navigating).

The following are the results I got.

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("Autonomous cars shift insurance liability toward manufacturers")
for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.dep_, token.head.text, token.head.pos_,
            [child for child in token.children])

Autonomous amod cars NOUN []
cars nsubj shift VERB [Autonomous]
shift ROOT shift VERB [cars, liability]
insurance compound liability NOUN []
liability dobj shift VERB [insurance, toward]
toward prep liability NOUN [manufacturers]
manufacturers pobj toward ADP []
```

Why my results are different from the documentation? For example, the syntactic dependents of "shift" has to be "cars, liability and toward". Also, the children of "liability" has to be only "insurance".

Answer (score 0):

The results are different because of two different package versions of Spacy.
In their documentation, they are using v2.3.0 which you can see in the top right corner of the code editor.

[image: Version screenshot]

I got the same result as yours when I used v2.2.4, it is possible that you are using the same version. So you should upgrade to v2.3.0 if you want same results as their documentation

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I have the version 2.3.2. `spacy.__version__
'2.3.2'`

Comment: So I will recommend you to downgrade the spacy version to v2.3.0.? Also can you mark my answer as accepted, if it solved your issue.